# Norwegian date in moment having double dot

Tags: momentjs, locale, date-formatting

I am getting a problem while using `moment.js` with *Norwegian* `locale`. The date is containing double dots after month, like below

> 11. des.. 2017

I have found that `moment-with-locales.js` in line 1009 contains a list of short dates. Months which contains a dot (.) results in a invalid date. Because dot (.) is also used as a separator in date format.

There is a ongoing discussion on [github](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/3652).

Is there any better solution to handle this?

Comment: The Github discussion recommends using the `MMM` formatter without a dot. Is that not an option?

Comment: No. It will create problem for SE (Swedish) or Danish (DK) locale, as mentioned in that discussion.

Comment: See maggiepint's [comment](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/3652#issuecomment-269043712):  _You can certainly customize the locale to omit the dots. See http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/month-names/ Unfortunately there's not much else to be done. In the locale space, there are a lot of matters of opinion._